# Drop unique index when having Primary Key index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE steps (
    hash_id text UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    depth integer
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX steps_hash_id_key ON steps(hash_id text_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX steps_pkey ON steps(hash_id text_ops);
```

But I'd like to remove the redundant UNIQUE index because `PRIMARY KEY` is already unique.

I've also many other tables linked to the `hash_id` of my `steps` table with foreign keys.

When I try to remove my `UNIQUE index` like this:

`ALTER TABLE steps DROP CONSTRAINT steps_hash_id_key;`

I get

```
ERROR:  cannot drop constraint steps_hash_id_key on table steps because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint steps_routes_step_hash_id_fkey on table steps_routes depends on index steps_hash_id_key
constraint steps_likes_dislikes_step_hash_id_fkey on table steps_likes_dislikes depends on index steps_hash_id_key
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

The matter is that I don't want to cascade delete anything, I'd just like to remove this duplicated unique index. Is it possible ?

Comment: That is curious.  I wonder if the primary key was added *after* the `unique`.  I would expect foreign keys to prefer the primary key.

Comment: Yes, this table used to have another primary key and `hash_id` was just unique. I removed the previous PK and set `hash_id` as PK, so now it has unique + pk indexes.

Comment: Drop the foreign key as well, switch the primary key, and then add the foreign key again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion in comments (@Gordon Linoff) here's a way to fix this issue:

- Drop foreign keys
- Drop Primary Keys and Unique Keys
- Recreate Primary Key only
- Recreate Foreign Keys

```
ALTER TABLE steps_routes DROP CONSTRAINT steps_routes_step_hash_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE steps_likes_dislikes DROP CONSTRAINT steps_likes_dislikes_step_hash_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE steps DROP CONSTRAINT steps_pkey;
ALTER TABLE steps DROP CONSTRAINT steps_hash_id_key;
ALTER TABLE steps ADD PRIMARY KEY (hash_id);
ALTER TABLE steps_routes ADD FOREIGN KEY (step_hash_id) REFERENCES steps(hash_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE steps_likes_dislikes ADD FOREIGN KEY (step_hash_id) REFERENCES steps(hash_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```